# slit's width in young's double slit experiment

Tags: double-slit-experiment

If we change slits' width in ydse, what changes will be seen in the fringe pattern and it's density
I found a source from a book saying[image]
but how could the pattern gets less sharp on increasing the width, if we increase the width less waves will be diffracted thus more sharp

please someone help me with question

Comment: If there is no slit how 'sharp' is the diffraction pattern?

Comment: What do you mean by "less waves will diffracted"?